# How many members can join in a single socket room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am recently started learning the Sockets concept. in that process I am learning about rooms and namespaces. in the rooms concept I got small doubt.

I searched for that, but I didn't get the answer. my question is `How many members can join in a single room?`. Is there any limit for the members to join in a single room.

Please help me with answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are no specific limits.  A room is just a Javascript data structure that contains the ids of all the connections that are in the room.  So, the only practical limit would be the small amount of memory it uses, but more likely it is limited only by how many simultaneous socket connections your server could have.

Comment: @chandrasekharreddykotha - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.